# how to decode a big number in a uri using in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, urldecode

in my javaScript program, I test the following code.
input: `$decodeURIComponent(598697613166239744)`

output: `598697613166239700`

why the number changed ? how can i avoid it ?

Comment: As [arcs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244004/how-to-decode-a-big-number-in-a-uri-using-in-javascript/42244093#42244093) suggests, you need a library to handle numbers like this. I would recommend: [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js)

Comment: I do not think this library can  sove my problem, because I need a decode  uri library.

Answer (score 2):

That is a general propbelm in Javascript. Your number ( 598697613166239744 ) is higher than the highest safe integer JavaScript can represent because of its [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Safe means that it can be represented exactly and correctly. Higher numbers are calculated and are estimates. So they generally are about in the right neighborhood, but not exactly.

You can verify this by running

```
console.log(598697613166239744)
console.log( Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER )
```

So the problem is not `decodeURIComponent()`.

To fix this either pack this number into a string or use a library that can deal with such numbers

Comment: `higher than the highest save number` - you mean highest **safe integer**

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the component as string
2. Create a Decimal.js instance on that string
3. Using Decimal.js methods, you can now manipulate this enormous number.

[JSFiddle (The library wouldn't load in SO for some reason, so i had to make a fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/3omkhdmk/)

Please ignore the `HTML` section in that fiddle. I had some problems loading the library so in the end i just dumped the code into the `HTML` section.

Here is the operative code for SO evaulation:

```
var uriComponent = "598697613166239744";

var d = new Decimal(uriComponent);

document.body.innerHTML += "<p>uriComponent: "+ uriComponent + "</p>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>parseInt will be wrong: "+ parseInt(uriComponent, 10) + "</p>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Decimal solution: "+ d.toString() + "</p><br>";

document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Decimal operation (divide by 2): "+ d.div(2).toString() + "</p>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Decimal operation (multiply by 2): "+ d.mul(2).toString() + "</p>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Decimal operation (modulus by 2): "+ d.mod(2).toString() + "</p>";
```